Error compiling Lua's SDL.dll library using Visual Studio 2019
My operating system is Windows 10 64 bit, and the downloaded version of Lua's sdl library is LuaSdl2_2.0.5-6.0
My operation steps are as follows:

First, download the SDL-Release-2.0.5.zip source code from GitHub

Download the Luasdl2_2.0.5-6.0.zip source code again

Unzip SDL-Release-2.0.5.zip source code

Add three projects (SDL, SDLMain, SDLtest) under the source code directory of SDL-lease-2.5.5 in Visual C to my solution

The compilation of SDL, SDLMain, and SDLtest projects resulted in SDL2.dll, SDL2.lib, SDLMain.lib, and SDLtest.lib

Create a new SDL library project in my solution for calling Lua 5.4.7, add existing items from the src directory of Lua sdl2_2.0.5-6.0

You can view the content shown in the picture
Unable to upload image!!!
(1) SDL(not lua) project:
step-1: add existing item from SDL-release-2.0.5\VisualC DIR.
step-2: build SDL2.dll、SDL2.lib、SDL2main.lib、SDL2test.lib is ok.
(2) lua SDL project:
step-1: add existing item from luasdl2-2.0.5-6.0\src DIR
step-2: Configuration Properties-->C/C++-->General-->Additional Dependencies-->
include "xxx\SDL-release-2.0.5\include" DIR
include "xxx\luasdl2-2.0.5-6.0\src", using common DIR
include "xxx\luasdl2-2.0.5-6.0\rocks"
include "xxx\luasdl2-2.0.5-6.0\extern\queen", using sys\queen.h
include "xxx\lua547\src"
step-3: Linker-->General-->Additional Library Directories-->
add my lua54.lib、SDL2.lib、SDL2main.lib、SDL2test.lib, and SDL2.dll copy to lua.exe Release DIR
-->Input: lua54.lib, SDL2.lib, SDL2main.lib, SDL2test.lib
step-4: build lua SDL project
step-5: as follows


When I clicked on generate, I didn't understand why there were 50 errors. These 50 errors seemed to be missing SDL2.lib, but I had already added and set them up, so I don't know why these errors still exist.
I can confirm that there is no problem with my Lua54.lib, as the Lua socket library has already been generated and tested for Lua sockets.
My configuration options are Release and x86
If you know what the problem is, feel free to give me some tips and suggestions. thank you.
I hope to receive an answer, thank you

Blockquote
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning C4244   '=': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data  SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\audio.c   125
Warning C4244   '=': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data  SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\audio.c   128
Warning C4244   '=': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data  SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\audio.c   130
Warning C4244   '=': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data  SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\display.c 67
Warning C4244   '=': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data  SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\events.c  273
Warning C4244   '=': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data  SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\events.c  275
Warning C4244   '=': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data  SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\events.c  396
Warning C4244   '=': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data  SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\rectangle.c   144
Warning C4244   '=': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data  SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\rectangle.c   145
Warning C4244   '=': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data  SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\rectangle.c   146
Warning C4244   '=': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data  SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\rectangle.c   147
Warning C4244   '=': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data  SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\thread.c  99
Warning C4244   '=': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'Uint16', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\window.c  593
Warning C4244   '=': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'Uint16', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\window.c  594
Warning C4244   '=': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'Uint16', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\window.c  595
Warning C4244   'function': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\haptic.c  766
Warning C4244   'function': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'Uint32', possible loss of data    SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\timer.c   173
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\audio.c   406
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\audio.c   429
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\display.c 91
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\display.c 131
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\display.c 152
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\display.c 174
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\display.c 201
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\display.c 225
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\display.c 226
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\display.c 250
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\display.c 305
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\events.c  141
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\events.c  142
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\events.c  185
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\events.c  202
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\events.c  203
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\events.c  222
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\events.c  240
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\events.c  241
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\events.c  262
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\events.c  263
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\events.c  351
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\gamecontroller.c  111
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\gamecontroller.c  135
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\gamecontroller.c  159
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\gamecontroller.c  181
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\gl.c  70
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\gl.c  71
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\gl.c  92
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\gl.c  232
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\haptic.c  60
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\haptic.c  314
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\haptic.c  358
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\haptic.c  483
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\haptic.c  528
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\haptic.c  529
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\haptic.c  626
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\haptic.c  704
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\joystick.c    39
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\joystick.c    63
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\joystick.c    87
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\joystick.c    128
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\joystick.c    235
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\joystick.c    254
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\joystick.c    276
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\joystick.c    294
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\keyboard.c    31
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\logging.c 47
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\logging.c 141
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\logging.c 170
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\logging.c 171
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\logging.c 201
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\logging.c 244
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\logging.c 245
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\mouse.c   64
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\mouse.c   65
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\mouse.c   95
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\mouse.c   96
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\mouse.c   97
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\mouse.c   98
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\mouse.c   286
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\mouse.c   287
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\renderer.c    81
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\renderer.c    141
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\renderer.c    253
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\renderer.c    254
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\renderer.c    255
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\renderer.c    256
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\renderer.c    908
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\renderer.c    909
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\window.c  613
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\window.c  674
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\window.c  675
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\window.c  693
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\window.c  694
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\window.c  735
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\window.c  736
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\window.c  773
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\window.c  774
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\window.c  894
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'int', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\window.c  895
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'SDL_Keycode', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\keyboard.c    91
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'SDL_Keycode', possible loss of data   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\keyboard.c    178
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'size_t', possible loss of data    SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\audio.c   780
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'Uint32', possible loss of data    SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\timer.c   132
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'Uint32', possible loss of data    SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\window.c  543
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Integer' to 'Uint8', possible loss of data SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\texture.c 140
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'lua_Number' to 'float', possible loss of data  SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\luasdl2_205_60_src\src\window.c  715
Error   LNK1120 49 unresolved externals SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\lua\Release\lua54-x86\clibs\SDL.dll  1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _arrayAppend SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\LuaModule\lua54\SDL\thread.obj   1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _arrayFree   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\LuaModule\lua54\SDL\rectangle.obj    1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _arrayInit   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\LuaModule\lua54\SDL\thread.obj   1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _BlendMode   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\LuaModule\lua54\SDL\SDL.obj  1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _commonBindEnum  SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\LuaModule\lua54\SDL\SDL.obj  1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _commonBindLibrary   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\LuaModule\lua54\SDL\SDL.obj  1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _commonBindObject    SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\LuaModule\lua54\SDL\SDL.obj  1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _commonGetEnum   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\LuaModule\lua54\SDL\keyboard.obj 1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _commonGetUserdata   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\LuaModule\lua54\SDL\audio.obj    1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _commonNewLibrary    SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\LuaModule\lua54\SDL\SDL.obj  1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _commonPush  SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\LuaModule\lua54\SDL\audio.obj    1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _commonPushEnum  SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\LuaModule\lua54\SDL\keyboard.obj 1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _commonPushErrno SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\LuaModule\lua54\SDL\audio.obj    1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _commonPushSDLError  SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\LuaModule\lua54\SDL\audio.obj    1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _commonPushUserdata  SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\LuaModule\lua54\SDL\events.obj   1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _RWOps   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\LuaModule\lua54\SDL\audio.obj    1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _RWOpsFunctions  SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\LuaModule\lua54\SDL\SDL.obj  1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _RWOpsSeek   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\LuaModule\lua54\SDL\SDL.obj  1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _RWOpsType   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\LuaModule\lua54\SDL\SDL.obj  1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _Surface SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\LuaModule\lua54\SDL\mouse.obj    1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _SurfaceFunctions    SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\LuaModule\lua54\SDL\SDL.obj  1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _tableGetBool    SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\LuaModule\lua54\SDL\audio.obj    1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _tableGetDouble  SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\LuaModule\lua54\SDL\renderer.obj 1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _tableGetEnum    SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\LuaModule\lua54\SDL\window.obj   1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _tableGetInt SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\LuaModule\lua54\SDL\audio.obj    1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _tableGetString  SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\LuaModule\lua54\SDL\audio.obj    1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _tableGetStringl SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\LuaModule\lua54\SDL\audio.obj    1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _tableGetUserdata    SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\LuaModule\lua54\SDL\renderer.obj 1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _tableIsType SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\LuaModule\lua54\SDL\audio.obj    1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _tableSetBool    SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\LuaModule\lua54\SDL\audio.obj    1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _tableSetDouble  SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\LuaModule\lua54\SDL\audio.obj    1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _tableSetEnum    SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\LuaModule\lua54\SDL\events.obj   1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _tableSetInt SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\LuaModule\lua54\SDL\audio.obj    1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _tableSetString  SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\LuaModule\lua54\SDL\events.obj   1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _tableSetStringl SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\LuaModule\lua54\SDL\audio.obj    1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _variantFree SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\LuaModule\lua54\SDL\channel.obj  1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _variantGet  SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\LuaModule\lua54\SDL\channel.obj  1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _variantPush SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\LuaModule\lua54\SDL\channel.obj  1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _videoGetColorRGB    SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\LuaModule\lua54\SDL\renderer.obj 1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _videoGetDisplayMode SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\LuaModule\lua54\SDL\display.obj  1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _videoGetLine    SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\LuaModule\lua54\SDL\renderer.obj 1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _videoGetPoint   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\LuaModule\lua54\SDL\rectangle.obj    1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _videoGetPoints  SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\LuaModule\lua54\SDL\rectangle.obj    1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _videoGetRect    SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\LuaModule\lua54\SDL\keyboard.obj 1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _videoGetRects   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\LuaModule\lua54\SDL\renderer.obj 1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _videoPushColorRGB   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\LuaModule\lua54\SDL\renderer.obj 1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _videoPushDisplayMode    SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\LuaModule\lua54\SDL\display.obj  1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _videoPushPoint  SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\LuaModule\lua54\SDL\window.obj   1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _videoPushRect   SDL (LuaModule\lua54\SDL)   D:\xxx\LuaModule\lua54\SDL\display.obj  1
Warning     unresolved import 'PyQt5'   PythonApplication1  D:\xxx\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication1.py 2


Why did you create a new project? Why not build with luarocks or create the project with cmake?
